# Variable referencing issue with an asynchronous call

Tags: javascript

I've been playing around with JavaScript and there's something I don't quite understand. I have this piece of code here:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(obj) {

    for( var p in obj.List )
    {               
        datas['id'] = obj.List[p].ListingId;
        datas['area'] = area;

        //console.log(datas);

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();              
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': datas['area'] }, function(results,status)
        {

            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.Ya, results[0].geometry.location.Za);

                datas['latlng'] = latlng;

                //console.log(datas);                       

            }                               
        });
     }      
});
```

Ok, now suppose the for loop runs 3 times. If we uncomment the first "console.log(datas)" line and run the page, in the console we see 3 "datas" objects with their own "id" and "area". If I comment that first "console.log(datas)" and uncomment the second "console.log(datas)" in the geocode callback, when I run the code, all 3 "datas" objects are exactly the same in terms of "id", "area", and "latlng". Whereas I expected the 3 "datas" objects would be different with their own latlngs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When is the function you pass to the `geocoder.geocode` function run? If it's not being run immediately then the for loop will run through all three times before the geocode function is run. That means that `datas['id']` and `datas['area']` will have been set to the last iteration of the loop... in which case you need to capture the datas array inside a closure for the geocode function.

In which case you'd need something like:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(obj) {

    for( var p in obj.List )
    {               
        datas['id'] = obj.List[p].ListingId;
        datas['area'] = area;

        //console.log(datas);

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();              
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': datas['area'] }, function(datas){ return function(results,status)
        {

            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.Ya, results[0].geometry.location.Za);

                datas['latlng'] = latlng;

                //console.log(datas);                       

            }                               
        }}(datas));
     }      
});
```

This prevents the datas variable as used by the anonymous function being updated by the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a scope problem. By the time that last `console.log` runs the `p` variable will already refer to the last obj. You need to capture `p` in a new scope.

```
for( var p in obj.List ) { 

  (function(p) {

    datas['id'] = obj.List[p].ListingId;
    datas['area'] = area;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': datas['area'] }, function(results,status) {
      ...
    });

  }(p));

}
```

Comment: Great - that fixed it! I still don't quite understand however why this fixes it. Could you elaborate on this a bit?

Comment: When the callback in `geocoder` runs, the loop has already finished thus the `p` variable will only refer to the last item that's why you _need_ to keep a reference to `p`. I found this link with more info http://zef.me/2843/javascript-the-scope-pitfall, you can also look for "closures javascript" on google, you'll find lots of useful stuff.

Comment: I have to admit, I'm a little confused by this as well, since `p` isn't used inside the callback. Is this by any chance turning `datas` into a local variable of the function scope? If that's the case then you don't need the `p` argument at all...

Comment: Ah I think I understand now. I didn't quite realize that the geocoder ran after that whole loop was finished (I thought the async call to it was immediate). Thanks both of you guys

Answer (score 0):

I think datas has to be declared as a global array? Has it?

Comment: I did make it global at one point but I don't recall it fixed it.